# Diferent angles in relativity time dilation

Tags: special-relativity

I have read that time dilation or length contraction only works if the inertial reference systems travel parallel, is that true? 
Where can I find examples where depending on the angle between the reference systems it is observed that there is no variance of time or length?

Comment: If your coordinate systems are not aligned in the standard configuration with $x$ parallel to $x'$,  you can transform first to a rotated coordinate system where the axes are aligned.  The spatial rotations do not affect lengths of times, so you see that the boosts do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always both time dilation and length contraction between two inertial frames of reference in which the origins are moving relative to each other. However, the length contraction only occurs along the direction of relative motion. It's customary and generally simplifies calculations a lot to choose coordinate systems in which the direction of relative motion is along the direction of the $x$ and $x'$ axis. But even if the relative motion isn't along the $x$ and $x'$ axis, length contraction will still occur, in the direction of the relative motion vector.